# My program only requests 1 permission at a time

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions

This program requires access both to a camera and to location. However, when a device needs to request both, it only requests ONE of those permissions, and does not request the other until I close my program and then reopen it. I can't figure out the issue.

```
protected void requestBoth() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MULT_KEY);
    }

    protected void requestLoc() {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCPERMISSION_KEY);
    }

    protected void requestCam() {
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMPERMISSION_KEY);
    }

public void request() {
    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        requestUpdates();
    } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestCam();
    } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestLoc();
    } else {
        requestBoth();
    }

 }
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            request();
        }

    }
```

Someone please help out! By the way, I purposefully left out the shouldShowRequestPermissionsRationale out of this question, as well as the onRequestPermissionsResult method, as I believed those to be irrelevant to the question. (I have even tried putting the request() call in onResume(), but that caused an infinite loop when a permission was denied and the user checked "do not show again". I am completely out of ideas.

Comment: Can't find any issue with this code, you may need to look for the issue in some other parts. Do you call this from your activity of a fragment? if it is the latter, then you may have issues with the FragmentManager

Comment: Show your callback code that is executed after the user deals with the permission requests please.

Answer (score 1):

Another efficent solution is to use RxJava and [RxPermission](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions)

So you can do something like this:

```
rxPermissions
    .requestEach(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
             Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    .subscribe(permission -> { // will emit 2 Permission objects
        if (permission.granted) {
           // `permission.name` is granted !
        } else if (permission.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale) {
           // Denied permission without ask never again
        } else {
           // Denied permission with ask never again
           // Need to go to the settings
        }
    });
```

or you can request each permissions combined:

```
rxPermissions
    .requestEachCombined(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
             Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    .subscribe(permission -> { // will emit 1 Permission object
        if (permission.granted) {
           // All permissions are granted !
        } else if (permission.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale)
           // At least one denied permission without ask never again
        } else {
           // At least one denied permission with ask never again
           // Need to go to the settings
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Ted Permission:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.1.0'
}
```

Make PermissionListener

```
PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPermissionGranted() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionDenied(ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied\n" + deniedPermissions.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


};
```

Start TedPermission

```
//Change your permission in this section, you can add any number of permissions\\
// You can also check whether user has given the permission or not \\

TedPermission.with(this)
    .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
    .setDeniedMessage("If you reject permission,you can not use this service\n\nPlease turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
    .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    .check();
```

For more info visit

https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The method to request both permissions must be `requestBoth()`:

```
protected void requestBoth() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MULT_KEY);
    }
```

Change your code to:

```
 if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
         //requestUpdates();
          requestBoth();

    } 
    ...
```

Comment: That section of his code has already verified that both permissions are granted and doesn't need to request any permissions at all.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can put it all in one String array like this

```java
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) Login.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, 100);
```